# Animate submenu with transform and display properties

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Ok so I've got this submenu in the sidebar, but I run into an issue when it comes to animating it. I have tried to use the `transform` property in combination with `display: none;`, but still it opens instantly. If I use only `transform`, it takes up the space… Is there any way around this, with transform or without it?

```
.hide-submenu {
    display: none;
    transform: scaleY(0);
}

.show-submenu {
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

Here's a Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvk6ku?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: what animation do you want to make exactly? on your stackblitz your animation works fine.

Comment: @TudorAlexandru same as the existing animation, but when it's closed it should not take the space under the submenu

Comment: Everything should slide down

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xq2z48

Comment: Well this is great...thank you @enno.void!